# Update 2 tables second does not get updated using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

Hello i am facing a very strange problem here. I have 2 tables joined in order to fetch data. Then after user edits data I want to update the tables separately. One of the tables gets updated and the other does not.

My Code:

```
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $activated = $_POST['activated'];
    $client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $apikey = $_POST['apikey'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];


    $update_rest_clients = $handler->prepare("UPDATE rest_api_clients
        SET contact_person = ?, address = ?, company = ?,
            activated = ?, phone_number = ? WHERE client_id = ? ");

    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(1, $contact);
    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(2, $address);
    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(3, $company);

    if ($activated == 'true') {
        $update_rest_clients->bindValue(4, 'yes');
    } else {
        $update_rest_clients->bindValue(4, 'no');
    }

    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(5, $client_id);
    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(6, $phone);

    $update_rest_clients->execute();
    $update_rest_clients->closeCursor();

    $update_api_key = $handler->prepare("UPDATE rest_api_keys
             SET api_key = ?, level = ? WHERE user_id = ? ");

    $update_api_key->bindValue(1, $apikey);
    $update_api_key->bindValue(2, $level);
    $update_api_key->bindValue(3, $client_id);

    $update_api_key->execute();
    $update_api_key->closeCursor();

    if ($update_api_key) {
        echo "success api key";
    } 

    if ($update_rest_clients) {
        echo "Success rest client";
    }
```

And the Ajax response in the browser:

```
Array
(
    [contact] => Name Surname
    [address] => Awesome Str. 8
    [company] => mycompany.com
    [apikey] => 09f9bae2fe72975f7da25d284139dc1ee
    [phone] => 00379305557229
    [level] => 10
    [activated] => true
    [client_id] => 3
)
<br />
success api keySuccess rest client
```

My PDO $handler:

```
try{
        $handler = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname."", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        $handler->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
```

This is the error info of the first query but still I don't understand why table is not getting updated.

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

How should I do it successfully?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if ($activated == 'true')` you checking for a string or boolean value here? Either way, check for possible errors.

Comment: i am checking for a string because the datastring from ajax comes as string

Comment: if this is ajax/jquery related, you'll have to post your code for that and the html.

Comment: but look at the response from the browser. I already get the data from ajax and 1 table is updated. Only the rest_api_clients is not updated and this is weird

Comment: are you sure this isn't a PDO error http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php or PHP error http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ? I don't know if you are doing the proper error checking.

Comment: i am using error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top of my php and i have no errors

Comment: The pdo error info gives me this: (
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: all I can think of now is to check the column types and their lengths. If the lengths are too short, MySQL will fail silently. That's the best I can think of at this point.

Comment: all the varchar type fields are set to 255 length and the collation is utf8mb4_general_ci i dont think there is any problemm with that right?

Comment: What table do you refer to as *first* table and *second* table?

Comment: the rest_api_clients is the first table and the rest_api_keys is the second table and only the rest_api_keys gets updated

Comment: No `WHERE` on the `UPDATEs`?  You are updating all rows?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

Comment: where exactly do you see that i do not have a WHERE on the updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like your client and phone binding values are the wrong way around, so you're trying to update on ID with a phone number which means it would fail if it starts with 0, since itll never match, nothing will get updated, however the query will still execute. See below:

```
$update_rest_clients = $handler->prepare("UPDATE rest_api_clients SET contact_person = ?, address = ?, company = ?, activated = ?, phone_number = ? WHERE client_id = ? ");

$update_rest_clients->bindValue(1, $contact);
$update_rest_clients->bindValue(2, $address);
$update_rest_clients->bindValue(3, $company);

if ($activated == 'true') {
    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(4, 'yes');
} else {
    $update_rest_clients->bindValue(4, 'no');
}

//I have swapped these around.
$update_rest_clients->bindValue(6, $client_id);
$update_rest_clients->bindValue(5, $phone);
```

Comment: can you believe that? so stupid of me. I will award bounty in 22 hours

Answer (score 0):

level is a  [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQl 5.7.

Use backticks **`** for field names.

Comment: i have the problemm with the other table. The table with level updates fine